# Wavelet decomposition of $C^{k}$-functions on smooth manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, harmonic-analysis, smooth-manifolds, approximation-theory, wavelets

**Background (compactly supported wavelet decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$):**
Fix compactly supported “mother and father wavelets” $\phi,\psi^{\epsilon}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\epsilon$ takes values in $I:=\{0,1\}^n \setminus \{(0,…,0)\}$.  Define the family of wavelets
$$
\phi_t(x) = \phi(x-t) \\
\psi_{(j,s,\epsilon)} = 2^{dj/2} \psi^{\epsilon}(2^jx-s),
$$
where $t,s\in \mathbb{Z}^d$, $j\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\epsilon \in I$.  For every integer $j$ abbreviate $\Lambda_j:=\{j\}\times \mathbb{Z}^d\times I$.

Since this forms an orthonormal system in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then any function therein can be decomposed as
$$
f = \sum_t \langle f,\phi_t\rangle\,\phi_t 
+ 
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda_j}\, 
    \langle f,\psi_{\lambda} \rangle \psi_{\lambda}.
\qquad\qquad \boldsymbol{(1)}
$$

[Theorem 5 of Meyer's book on the topic][1], states that there are constants $C_0,C_1>0$ such that wavelet coefficients can be bounded as follows
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle f,\phi_t\rangle &\leq C_0\,\|f\|_{\infty}
\\
\langle f,\psi_{\lambda} \rangle & \leq C_1 2^{-n/j\, -j/s}\|f\|_{C^{s,1}},
\end{aligned}
$$
whenever $f\in C^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\|\cdot\|_{C^{s,1}}$ is the H"{o}lder norm, $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is the uniform norm, and $C_0,C_1>0$ are constants only depending on the dimension $d$ and on the smoothness level $s$.

---

**Question:** If $\mathcal{M}$ is instead a ($C^{\infty}$) smooth manifold then does such a wavelet decomposition hold for any function $f \in C^s(\mathcal{M})$ where $s$ is a positive integer.  By ``such a wavelet decomposition'' I mean compactly supported $\psi$ and $\psi^{\epsilon}$ for which (1) holds.

Comment: From the point of view of manifolds, a natural definition of a "wavelet on a manifold" would be any function that extends to a wavelet on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. when your manifold is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.   Then your previous theorem would naturally extend to a theorem about functions on manifolds.

Comment: You may find this book useful: https://books.google.ca/books/?id=rGrMBQAAQBAJ